# MongoDB aggregate using $match with $expr with array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

MongoDB 5.0.9

I am trying to get

1. value of application within course and their specification
2. value of paid application ( status : paid) based on course and their specification

*courses collection having multiple courses with specification which might be there maybe not*

```json
[
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62aab6669b3740313d881a30"
      },
      "course_name": "Master",
      "fees": "Rs.1000.0/-",
      "course_specialization": [
        {
          "spec_name": "Social Work",
          "is_activated": true
        }
      ],
      "college_id": {
        "$oid": "628dfd41ef796e8f757a5c13"
      },
      "is_pg": true
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62aab6669b3740313d881a38"
      },
      "college_id": {
        "$oid": "628dfd41ef796e8f757a5c13"
      },
      "course_name": "BBA",
      "fees": "Rs.1000.0/-",
      "is_pg": false,
      "course_specialization": null
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "628f3967cb69fc0789e69181"
      },
      "course_name": "BTech",
      "fees": "Rs.1000.0/-",
      "course_specialization": [
        {
          "spec_name": "Computer Science and Engineering",
          "is_activated": true
        },
        {
          "spec_name": "Mutiple Specs",
          "is_activated": true
        }
      ],
      "college_id": {
        "$oid": "628dfd41ef796e8f757a5c13"
      },
      "is_pg": false
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "628f35a1cb69fc0789e6917e"
      },
      "course_name": "Bachelor",
      "fees": "Rs.1000.0/-",
      "course_specialization": [
        {
          "spec_name": "Social Work",
          "is_activated": true
        }
      ],
      "college_id": {
        "$oid": "628dfd41ef796e8f757a5c13"
      },
      "is_pg": false
    }
  ],
```

*Student Application forms collection where we are storing student application forms details*

```json
[
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62cd476adbc878a0490e20ee"
      },
      "spec_name1": "Social Work",
      "spec_name2": "",
      "spec_name3": "",
      "student_id": {
        "$oid": "62cd1374dbc878a0490e20a5"
      },
      "course_id": {
        "$oid": "62aab6669b3740313d881a30"
      },
      "current_stage": 2.5,
      "declaration": true,
      "payment_info": {
        "payment_id": "123458",
        "status": "paid"
      },
      "enquiry_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1657620330432"
        }
      },
      "last_updated_time": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1657621796062"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62cd476adbc878a0490e20ef"
      },
      "spec_name1": "",
      "spec_name2": "",
      "spec_name3": "",
      "student_id": {
        "$oid": "62cd1374dbc878a0490e20a5"
      },
      "course_id": {
        "$oid": "62aab6669b3740313d881a38"
      },
      "current_stage": 2.5,
      "declaration": true,
      "payment_info": {
        "payment_id": "123458",
        "status": "paid"
      },
      "enquiry_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1657620330432"
        }
      },
      "last_updated_time": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1657621796062"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62cdc12000b820f5ea58cc60"
      },
      "spec_name1": "Social Work",
      "spec_name2": "",
      "spec_name3": "",
      "student_id": {
        "$oid": "62cdad90a9b64d58b15e6976"
      },
      "course_id": {
        "$oid": "628f35a1cb69fc0789e6917e"
      },
      "current_stage": 6.25,
      "declaration": false,
      "payment_info": {
        "payment_id": "",
        "status": ""
      },
      "enquiry_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1657651488511"
        }
      },
      "last_updated_time": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1657651987155"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Desired output with every specification within the course

```json
[
    "_id": {
      "coursename": "Master",
      "spec": "Social Work",
      "Application_Count": 1,
      "Paid_Application_Count:0
    },
  {
    "_id": {
      "coursename": "Bachelor"
      "spec":"" ,
      "Application_Count": 1,
      "Paid_Application_Count:0
    },
      {
    "_id": {
      "coursename": "BBA"
      "spec":"" ,
      "Application_Count": 1,
      "Paid_Application_Count:1
    },
]
```

**Aggregation Query**

```
[{
 $match: {
  college_id: ObjectId('628dfd41ef796e8f757a5c13')
 }
}, {
 $project: {
  _id: 1,
  course_name: 1,
  course_specialization: 1
 }
}, {
 $unwind: {
  path: '$course_name',
  includeArrayIndex: 'course_index',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
 }
}, {
 $unwind: {
  path: '$course_specialization',
  includeArrayIndex: 'course_specs_index',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
 }
}, {
 $lookup: {
  from: 'studentApplicationForms',
  'let': {
   id: '$_id',
   spec: '$course_specialization.spec_name'
  },
  pipeline: [
   {
    $match: {
     $expr: {
      $and: [
       {
        $eq: [
         '$course_id',
         '$$id'
        ]
       },
       {
        $eq: [
         '$spec_name1',
         '$$spec'
        ]
       }
      ]
     }
    }
   },
   {
    $project: {
     student_id: 1,
     payment_info: 1,
     spec_name1: 1,
     spec_name2: 1,
     spec_name3: 1
    }
   }
  ],
  as: 'student_application'
 }
}, {
 $unwind: {
  path: '$student_application',
  includeArrayIndex: 'application',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
 }
}, {
 $facet: {
  course: [
   {
    $group: {
     _id: {
      course_name: '$course_name',
      spec: '$course_specialization'
     },
     count: {
      $count: {}
     }
    }
   }
  ],
  declatration: [
   {
    $group: {
     _id: {
      course_name: '$course_name',
      spec: '$course_specialization'
     },
     count_dec: {
      $sum: {
       $cond: [
        '$student_application.declaration',
        1,
        0
       ]
      }
     }
    }
   }
  ],
  payment: [
   {
    $group: {
     _id: {
      course_name: '$course_name',
      spec: '$course_specialization'
     },
     payment: {
      $sum: {
       $eq: [
        '$student_application.payment_info.status',
        'paid'
       ]
      }
     }
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}]
```

Problem :

1. I am able to get application count but it is not getting unique value if 2 specs are same  then duplicate value is coming as you can  see on sample application collection `Social Work` is in two different course . So my aggregations is not grouping them based in course name.specs
2. Not able to find correct `Paid_Application_Count` and `Application_Count`

Update :

Updated JSON Data Matching use cases with different type of data

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G-Gng2_IzJs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in several different ways, I took the liberty to simplify the pipeline a little bit.

I will just mention that the structure does not fully make sense to me, and there are some additional contradictions between the sample input you provided and the "text" description/pipeline description.
Just a tiny example is `payment_info_status` being `paid` in the sample and `capture` in the pipeline.

These things will not change the pipeline structure, will just need to be fixed by you based on the actual needs.

```
db.courses.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      course_name: 1,
      course_specialization: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$course_specialization",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "studentApplicationForms",
      "let": {
        courseId: "$_id",
        spec: {
          $ifNull: [
            "$course_specialization.spec_name",
            ""
          ]
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$spec_name1",
                    "$$spec"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$courseId",
                    "$course_id"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            student_id: 1,
            payment_info: 1,
            spec_name1: 1,
            spec_name2: 1,
            spec_name3: 1,
            declaration: 1,
            
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            },
            declatration: {
              $sum: {
                $cond: [
                  "$declaration",
                  1,
                  0
                ]
              }
            },
            paid: {
              $sum: {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$payment_info.status",
                      "paid"
                    ]
                  },
                  1,
                  0
                ]
              }
            },
            
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "student_application"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        coursename: "$course_name",
        spec: "$course_specialization.spec_name",
        Application_count: {
          $ifNull: [
            {
              $first: "$student_application.count"
            },
            0
          ]
        },
        Declaration_count: {
          $ifNull: [
            {
              $first: "$student_application.declatration"
            },
            0
          ]
        },
        Paid_Application_Count: {
          $ifNull: [
            {
              $first: "$student_application.paid"
            },
            0
          ]
        },
        
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1jMKi1Ni2y1)